# read float from SQLite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I used the codes below to load data(float) and store in an array.
My oject has one float field 'value' (setValue,getValue to read or write value)

```
rowData=(char*)sqlite3_colum_text(statement,0);
float v=[[NSString  initWithUTF8String:rowData] floatValue];
[myObject setValue:v];
[myArray addObject:myObject];
```

If I read the value from the array using
    float tem=[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] getValue];

I found all values are not correct, everyone is 0.00000000000000

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are stored as float numbers in database you should get them using `sqlite3_column_double` function, not `sqlite3_column_text`

Comment: Can you please give me any example?